# To draw circle in which color change time to time in android

Tags: android

How can i draw circle in which circle will fill with different color slowly & one bell ring when circle is completely fill.

Comment: Don't duplicate your own questions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use methods provided by timer class. Use timer.schedule() and there are many more. Explore and use them.